# Warning message in Mysqli: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using this code and i try to run it but it shows this error and try to fix it but i don't know how? Can anyone help me? :

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/u330779411/public_html/Register.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/u330779411/public_html/Register.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/u330779411/public_html/Register.php on line 13
```

Here is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$matric_number = $_POST['matric_number'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Users (name, matric_number, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $matric_number, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Is it

Comment: `var_dump($statement);` its probably going to say false

Comment: @Dagon means? the code is not correct?

Comment: is it false? is so there is an error with mysqli_prepare()

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> **mysqli_prepare()** returns a statement object or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

Since your warning states that a boolean was given, it is likely that an error occurred. I would suggest doing `var_dump($statement)` as @Dagon suggested to check if `$statement` is set to `false`.

You might also want to check `$con`. I am assuming that you omitted that part and that you initialized it properly earlier in the code, but make sure you are checking for [`mysqli_connect_error()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) as well.